# GridViewDataColumn Aggregate Function Visibility

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, telerik, radgridview

Having a `GridViewDataColumn` witch has a Binding on the `IsVisible` Property and a aggregate function, setting the `IsVisible="False"` doesn't hide the aggregate function in the group header:

```
<telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Title" 
                            IsVisible="{Binding IsVisibleProperty}"
                            DataMemberBinding="{Binding SomeProperty}" >
    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.AggregateFunctions>
         <telerik:SumFunction Caption="Some Caption: "/>
    </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.AggregateFunctions>
</telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to execute the following code every time, the `IsVisible` property of a column has changed:

```
foreach (var col in GridWithAggregateFunctions.Columns)
        {
            if (!col.IsVisible)
            {
                foreach (var func in col.AggregateFunctions.ToList())
                {
                    col.AggregateFunctions.Remove(func);
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a related issue for showing only one of the  aggregate functions in the group header in the [Telerik forums](https://www.telerik.com/forums/radgridview-group-header-with-aggregatefunctions). The answer there also applies to your issue since it is essentially the same problem.

> Regarding the template structure and the internal logic of the `GridViewGroupRow` you cannot predefine this behavior in such manner. If you take a look at the default template of `GridViewGroupRow` you can see the element `AggregateResulsList`, which displays the results of the aggregate functions. This part internally handles the aggregates and **there is no way to "instruct" it to display only the first function in the header and to ignore the rest**.

Consequently, you cannot hide single aggregate functions, but you only hide all.

> However you may hide all aggregates by creating a simple style targeted at `GridViewGroupRow` and set `ShowHeaderAggregates` property to `False`, as shown below:
>
> ```
> <Style TargetType="{x:Type telerik:GridViewGroupRow}">
>   <Setter Property="ShowHeaderAggregates" Value="False"/>
> </Style>
> ```

Comment: You are absolutely right, you cannot see it with my supplied code, but I had multiple aggregates, and aimed to show them only if the column is visible.